# Ubuntu 20.04 stops responding after few minutes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pop-os

I use only Ubuntu in my laptop.
I have been using Ubuntu in this
laptop for around one year. Suddenly
this problems raising-

1. When I open the PC it works fine for 4-5 minutes. Then suddenly nothing works. Applications do not open. But I'm able to navigate to directories. Mouse pointer works fine. I checked `top` and the CPU usage is around 30-40% and memory is also 20-30%.
2. Assuming it's an OS problem or GPU driver related problem I installed the latest POPOS distro and the problem remain same. Sometimes the icons of upper right corner(settings, wifi etc) disappears. Command line does not work, typing commands is possible but it says input/output error. So I had to switch off the PC from the power button.

I'm assuming this is not an OS issue rather it's a hardware issue but I'm very new to this. Is replacing hard disk to SSD might solve the problem?

System configuration:
core i7 9th gen
nvidia 940 mx

Comment: You can try booting a live system from a pendrive, if that does not exhibit any issues it's likely that your harddrive is the culprit

Comment: Do you frequently use it in a dusty environment? or one with lots of cat or dog fur?  If so, a year is a good time to open it up and give it a good clean.  Use artists brushes and a vacuum cleaner (btw, it's possible to get cheap - $10 to $20 -  little kits that come with brushes and adaptors and small hoses & nozzles you can attach to standard size vacuum cleaner hoses.  often sold as computer cleaning kits or car cleaning kits).